# Changing default locale of struts2

Tags: struts2, internationalization, locale

How can I modify struts2 default locale specified in struts.properties file as struts.locale ?

The default locale is "en" and i need to change it to "en_Us"

I tried as follows

```
<constant name="struts.locale" value="en_US" />
```

in my struts.xml file.

Comment: And then what happened?

Comment: I'm still getting locale as "en" only. But i need to change it because I have files with names like message-resources_en_US.properties.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late answer, but at someday somebody will find it as what he or she was looking for for long time.

The Struts2 framework sets the default locale based on language preferences of a browser, that is, it looks at `Accept-language` request header, and if not finding it then go to the struts properties for this.

So, if you want to change to the locale en_US, then you should set it in the browser parameters, set as first prefered language.

If you want to change this behavior, you may write interceptor which will set needed locale for the ActionContext.
Here reference to the API
`http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html#setLocale(java.util.Locale)`
Don't forget to put your interceptor in the interceptors stack in the struts.xml file.

Tutorial about creating your own interceptors:
`http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_interceptors.htm`

Hope, it will help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Yan Pak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40072349/687315), use the following custom interceptor to hard-code the locale, ignoring whatever Struts is trying to do based on the browser's `Accept-Language` header.

```java
import java.util.Locale;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class USLocaleInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public void destroy() { }

  @Override
  public void init() { }

  @Override
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    invocation.getInvocationContext().setLocale(Locale.US);
    return invocation.invoke();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I add that this new interceptor should be called *before* the default `param` interceptor, which uses it for number formatting.