# Strtus 2 bad format in textfield

Tags: javascript, java, struts2

i have a problem with format number in Struts 2 Java EE.

I get a double from de DataBase for example 1000,3 but  , when i try to print this value in the textfield .... , this value show like this 1.000,3 witch de dot, and i want to show the number with-out the dot . Thx.

```
<td> <s:textfield name="example[%{#stat.index}].Import" id="Import%{#stat.index}" onBlur="Validate(this)"/>
```

Validate is only a JavaScript function witch Regex thx.

Comment: What type is your `example[%{#stat.index}].Import`? It is probably your js function problem try to remove it.

Comment: example[%{#stat.index}].Import its a Double , js its ok its only this function  Validate(object){
  var RegExPattern =/^\d{1,6}(\,\d{2})?$/;
  var RegExPattern2 =/^\d{1,6}(\,\d{1})?$/;
  var campo=object.value;
  if(!campo.trim().match(RegExPattern)){
   if(!campo.trim().match(RegExPattern2)){ 
    alert("formato de precio no válido. Formato aceptado '0,00'");
    object.value="";
    object.focus();
   }   
  }

Comment: I debug the program and all double variable in action or BaseDate are ok , the problem its only in struts 2 in the textfield :S

Comment: Format a number as explained http://stackoverflow.com/a/23084580/573032